# Range data annotation is not working as expected, any idea?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I assume the validation check will allow any input value from 1 to 30. But, it prompts for error when I input a value with 4 to 9 in this field. Any advise? Please...

remarks: My project is based on "MVC4 Web Application + Razor View Engine + C# .net".

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

[Range(1, 30, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.ErrorMessage), ErrorMessageResourceName = "RangeErrorMsg")]
public int HowManyDays { get; set; }
```

Below is my Razor view source

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Resources.Booking.Duration
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.HowManyDays)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HowManyDays)
</div>
```

I have no way to upload my screen dump as I need at least 10 reputation to do so. Weird, it shows alert for value in range of 4 to 9 ONLY. Btw, I have "DataAnnotationsExtensions.MVC3" NuGet package installed. But, I did try to unstalled it without luck.

Comment: I just tried it here, and it works, try posting more info

Comment: I added the source of my Razor view.

Comment: I found the root cause why there was a weird validation issue. Because there is a JS library loaded in _Layout.cshtml. <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-2.5.3.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: Simply mention [Range(1, 30)] and give a try

Comment: As I mentioned in last reply, the issue is fixed once I removed the  JS lib "modernizr".

Answer (score 0):

Your second argument in `EditorFor` doesn't make any sense.
Take a look at [EditorFor help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee402949%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) or just on examples of its use on SO (this site).
This probably breaks your view and you get no validation.
To begin with, just remove the comma and the number, see if that works, if not look for examples on how to use `EditorFor`.

**Edit**

Your comment renders my answer completely irrelevant. You should be accurate as to what you put for public to see. 
Anyway, try to see if this successfully answered question solves your problem: 
[Range DataAnnotation Doesn't Seem to Be Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480140/range-dataannotation-doesnt-seem-to-be-working-in-net-3-5)

Please let me know if this helps.
Thanks.

Comment: I removed the comma and the number. Actually, my latest copy of source code has no comma and the number. It was just the way I "try & error" on previous stage.

Comment: As I mentioned in last reply, the issue is fixed once I removed the  JS lib "modernizr". I found that weird range validation effect is only occurred in javascript detection layer (http form is not yet POST).