# client side unobtrusive validation

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

Server side validation works fine(once i submit the form)
but client side doesnt work.

In my layout :

```
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

bundle:

```
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                   "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                   "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js",
                   "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"));
```

In my config file:

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

I am using Data annotations in my model & MVC 5

VM:

```
    public class LocationWorkingHoursVM 
{
    public int LocationID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Range(0,1)]
    public decimal?[] Hours { get; set; }
    public string BankHolidays { get; set; }     
}
```

It is rendered as :

```
<input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Nullable`1 must be a number." id="Hours_0_" name="Hours[0]" type="text" value="8.0" />
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Hours" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
```

What am i missing?

Comment: Is there any error of missing scripts on your console? (FF or Chrome). And your data annotations have any required message with an error message?

Comment: No errors in console, no messages. However i just noticed that i get client validation for the type of fields. E.g. if i start typing characters in an int field it will turn to red.

Comment: If it's turning to red that means is doing the validation, if you want validation more precisely, you need to specify that the field is required, if it's required, the validation should stop you from posting something empty or invalid. E.g. [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is obligatory")]

Comment: the client side validation is only working for the the type. E.g. I add the following annotation  [Range(0, 1], but its not happening on the client

Comment: For example atm as soon as i tab out of an numeric box having typed characters. The box will turn red. Is it possible to have the same behaviour having data annotations ?

Comment: Can you post your Model class here?

Comment: @den There is no issue in Model Class. Which version of jquery and  jquery.validate are you using in project? Just make sure if you are using latest version of jquery then must update jquery.validate to latest version.

Comment: I use VS2013 so I have updated everything from nuget manager to the latest version

Answer (score 1):

It was because I was using my own template for EditorFor helper. However I had it defined as

```
TextBoxFor(r=>r.model, new { @class= "foo")})
```

is it possible to make it work using my template ?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these two lines to your mainlayout and try again

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.12.0/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/4.0/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using  jQuery 1.9.1 or later version just make sure you are using

jQuery Validation (at least 1.11.1)
Microsoft jQuery Unobtrusive Validation (at least 2.0.30116.0)
Microsoft jQuery Unobtrusive Ajax (at least 2.0.30116.0)

[MVC data annotations range validation not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15370768/mvc-data-annotations-range-validation-not-working-properly#answer-17705536)